# How does [github] section of .gitconfig work?

Tags: git, github, git-config

I'm wondering how github can read in these values?  I could see a use of this for deployments etc. if I can define my own, custom sections.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GitHub cannot read those values. If some random company on the other side of the world could just willy-nilly read any arbitrary files on your computer, that would be truly scary.

But of course any program *you* run on *your* computer can read those values. Including, for example, the `hub` command or the `github` command, which are two popular commandline clients for GitHub.

Comment: So if you don't use hub or github commands or github clients, then those settings are not used when you're pushing a repo to GitHub?

Comment: @Misha: Correct; those config parameters are not part of git.

Comment: @Misha M: No, the normal `git` client doesn't use them. But your own shell scripts or git hooks could, for example.

Comment: +1 for will nilly reminds me of the old net zero commercials. classic.