# Which programs do use the [github] section in .gitconfig?

Tags: git, github

I haven't looked into my .gitconfig for a while. Now I can see the `[github]` section in it, e.g.

```
[github]
        user = <user>
        token = <token>
```

I wonder what is the purpose of this section? Which programs make use of it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4269732/218196. I think the purpose is clear (it is authentication information after all). If you are asking for a list of applications, then this question is "not constructive" IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The normal git client doesn't use them. But your own shell scripts or
>   git hooks could, for example
>
> GitHub cannot read those values. If some random company on the other
>   side of the world could just willy-nilly read any arbitrary files on
>   your computer, that would be truly scary.
>
> But of course any program you run on your computer can read those
>   values. Including, for example, the hub command or the github command,
>   which are two popular commandline clients for GitHub.

Source: [How does [github] section of .gitconfig work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269732/how-does-github-section-of-gitconfig-work)